# How do I use IEnumerable with moq It.Is

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

When checking that the correct data is being used to call a method I can do this:

```
mockedClass.Verify(method => method.WriteToConsole(It.Is<Result>(item => item.Name == "Bob" && item.Age == 44)));
```

where Results is an object that is the output from a Linq query:

```
 public class Result
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

However, I also use IEnumerable as the input to a 2nd method.

How do I amend the Verify above to check that the IEnumerable of Results contains Results I can test against.

```
mockedClass.Verify(method => method.WriteListToConsole(It.Is<IEnumerable<ResultRecord>>(item => What GOES HERE?)));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"item" at that point is an `IEnumerable<ResultRecord>`.  Just write what you want to test.

Something like this?

```
mockedClass.Verify(method => method.WriteListToConsole(It.Is<IEnumerable<ResultRecord>>(item => item.Count() == 1 && item.ToList()[0].SomeProperty == "Something")));
```